# text-align: center didn't work

Tags: css, text-align

I am trying to use python flask to develop a small website, but I can't figure out why that text-align: center didn't work.

there is a form variable passed into the html page, used to print the error message.

```
{% for message in form.name.errors %}
<div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
{% endfor %}

{% for message in form.message.errors %}
    <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

and the class `flash` define:

```
/* Message flashing */
.flash{
    background-color: #FBB0B0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

And it didn't work, it always show up in the left side, anybody know why?

I try this:

```
{% for message in form.name.errors %}
    <div style="background-color: #FBB0B0; text-align: center;">{{ message }}</div>
{% endfor %}

{% for message in form.message.errors %}
    <div style="background-color: #FBB0B0; text-align: center;">{{ message }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

it works, but when I put it into css file:

```
.flash{
    background-color: #FBB0B0;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

did't work.

Comment: That code will center the content of `.flash` not center the element itself.

Comment: Are you trying to center the text *in* the div or center the div itself?

Comment: @BSMP yep, in div itself it can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your dev tools (right click and 'inspect element') to see the problem. As the others have said, that will center the contents of that div. To center the div itself it has to be:

1. `display: block;` (which divs normally are)
2. Given a width
3. `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score -1):

You've not really given us sufficient information, it depends what `{{ message }}` resolves to.

But here you can see how different elements behave:

```css
.flash{
    background-color: #FBB0B0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center; 
}

.inner {
  width: 100px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  }

.inner-margin {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flash">Message</div>

<div class="flash"><div class="inner">Message</div></div>

<div class="flash"><div class="inner inner-margin">Message</div></div>
```

As you can see, 'flash' with just text works fine, but when you insert an 'inner' div with width, it fails. Add margins to that div with 'inner-margin' and it works again.

Answer (score -2):

Text-align in working with text...it will not center the element itself...

Comment: That's not true. E.g., if the parent component is `display: block; text-align: center` and the child component is `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`, the child component will be horizontally centered.